Instaloader stopped downloading at 12th posts
Instaloader newest version 4.12.1 on Python 3.11.5 stopped downloading at the 12th post without raising any exception even though the user has 48 downloadable posts.
L = instaloader.Instaloader(
        download_videos=False,
        download_video_thumbnails=False,
        save_metadata=False,
        user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        )
    # L.login("USER", "PASS")
    full_directory_path = os.path.join(root, username)
    if not os.path.exists(full_directory_path):
        os.makedirs(full_directory_path)
    L.dirname_pattern = full_directory_path
    L.download_profile(username,profile_pic=False)
    print(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT + "\n* Download complete\n.")

This is my code, I have tried to download with an account logged in as well but it does not even download a single post (no exception was raised).

profile thuwu_ could also be downloaded anonymously. Retrieving posts
from profile thuwu_.

Download complete .

Process finished with exit code 0

The problem here was it used to run flawlessly, I don't know what the problem here. And I tried to change my IP also but that does not work either.

fixed in latest version
update to Version 4.13
https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader/releases/tag/v4.13
